# Uri multi-languages with zend translate

Tags: zend-framework, routes, uri, zend-translate

I have a problem in making url multilanguage with zend because all the guides that I have followed have not worked
I want to have url like

`localhost/compare/public/en/controller/action`

`localhost/compare/public/it/controller/action`

Can you help?

This is my project structure 
Unfortunately, that does not make me load

-compare

```
   -application
       -configs
           application.ini
       -controllers
           ErrorController.php
           IndexController.php
       -layouts
           -scripts
               main.phtml
               nav.phtml
       -models
       -views
           -scripts
               -index
                    index.phtml
                    ...
       Bootstrap.php
   -languages
       en.php
       it.php
   -library
       -Zend
   -public
       -css
       -js
       index.php
```

This is bootstrap

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected $_view;   

    protected function _init()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    }

    protected function _initLanguage()
    {
        $locale = new Zend_Locale();
        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);  
        $translationPath = dirname( APPLICATION_PATH ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'languages';
        $translate = new Zend_Translate('array', $translationPath, $locale);
        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
        Zend_Validate_Abstract::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
        Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
    }

    protected function _initViewSettings()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $this->_view = $this->getResource('view');
    }

    protected function _initDefaultModuleAutoloader()
    {
        $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $loader->registerNamespace('App_');
        $this->getResourceLoader()
             ->addResourceType('modelResource','models/resources','Resource');  
    }

    protected function _initDbParms()
    {
        $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname'   => 'my_compare'
                    ));  
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
    }

}
```

This is application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1

phpSettings.display_errors = 1

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"

bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

appnamespace = "Application"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1

phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1

phpSettings.display_errors = 1

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```